# ggplot legend missing / add new line from different dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, legend, axes

as a beginner with R i try my first plotting-steps with ggplot.
Now I have a question concerning following situation:

I have a dataframe with numeric values from a river with it's outflow/second and the date (day).

Example (year 2011):

```
str(max2011.df)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  2 variables:
$ jahr   : Date, format: "2011-01-04" "2011-01-07" "2011-01-09" ...
$ liter_s: num  49.5 55.5 65 66.5 64 ...

head(max2011.df)
        jahr liter_s
1 2011-01-04   49.47
2 2011-01-07   55.46
3 2011-01-09   64.97
4 2011-01-10   66.47
5 2011-01-11   63.97
6 2011-01-13  103.03
```

Here is the plot:

[image]

I used the code below to generate the plot:

```
ggplot(data=max2011.df,
       aes(x = jahr, y = liter_s)
       ) +

  ggtitle("Einzelereignis 1\n Januar 2011") +

  geom_line(size = 1.5) +

  xlab("Zeit") + ylab ("liter_s") +

  theme_bw()+

  theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour="grey"), 
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "grey"),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(colour = "grey"),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(colour = "grey"),
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black"),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=14),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=14),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.title = element_text(colour = "blue")
        ) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("2 days"),
               labels = date_format("%d\n%b")
               )+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(40,220,20))
```

How can i add 1) the legend to this plot?
2) another axis (at side 4, right)?
3) another line, coming from a different dataframe which should be connected to the new axis at side 4 (right)?

I searched for a solution for example here
[How to add legend to ggplot manually? - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496984/how-to-add-legend-to-ggplot-manually-r) but wasn't succesful.

May someone can help me here?
Thank you in advance

```
dput(max2011.df[1:5,])
structure(list(jahr = structure(c(14978, 14981, 14983, 14984, 
14985), class = "Date"), liter_s = c(49.47, 55.46, 64.97, 66.47, 
63.97)), .Names = c("jahr", "liter_s"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

dput(klima2011.df[1:5,])
structure(list(datum = structure(c(14975, 14976, 14977, 14978, 
14979), class = "Date"), eistag = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), frosttag = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), temp_luft_2m = c(-2.31, -1.68, -3.3, -7.5, -7.65
), niederschlag_mm = c(0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0), temp_boden_5cm = c(1.3, 
1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3), luftfeuchte_rel = c(97.01, 92.56, 91.52, 
95.69, 93.84)), .Names = c("datum", "eistag", "frosttag", "temp_luft_2m", 
"niederschlag_mm", "temp_boden_5cm", "luftfeuchte_rel"), row.names = 2619:2623, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You can shorten your theme code quite a bit. For example, `panel.grid = element_line(colour="grey")` will take care of all the grid lines. `axis.line=element_line(colour="black")` will take care of both axis lines.

Comment: To add lines from two different data frames, it's better to you stack the data frames (for example, using `bind_rows` from `dplyr` or base `rbind`) and then add a column marking the source data frame. Then  map that source column to, say, colour. If you provide samples of both data frames, we can show you how. Paste in the output of `dput` to add the data. For example, `dput(df1[1:10, ])` and `dput(df2[1:10,])`.

Comment: Hi and thank you for the answer! I edited my main post with the dput output. From the 2nd dataframe especially i need the column "niederschlag_mm" (precipitation).