# Add legend to ggplot histogram plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I plotted histogram and kde's of a vector with ggplot in R. Now I'd like to add a legend containing the three kde plots --> "rectangular", "epanechnikov" and "gaussian". I just can't make it work!

```
v1 = data.frame(x=rnorm(500,30,9))
ggplot(data=v1, aes(x=x)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=2, color="grey", fill="white") +
  geom_density(aes(y=2 * ..count..), kernel="rectangular", color="orange") + 
  geom_density(aes(y=2 * ..count..), kernel="epanechnikov", color="red") + 
  geom_density(aes(y=2 * ..count..), kernel="gaussian", color="blue") + 
  scale_color_manual(labels=c("rectangular", "epanechnikov","gaussian"),
                     values=c("orange"="orange", "red"="red", "blue"="blue"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *so* close. As suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/24497113:

```r
ggplot(data=v1, aes(x=x)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=2, color="grey", fill="white") +
  geom_density(aes(y=2 * ..count.., color="rectangular"), kernel="rectangular") + 
  geom_density(aes(y=2 * ..count.., color="epanechnikov"), kernel="epanechnikov") + 
  geom_density(aes(y=2 * ..count.., color="gaussian"), kernel="gaussian") + 
  scale_color_manual(labels=c("rectangular", "epanechnikov","gaussian"),
                     values=c("rectangular"="orange", "epanechnikov"="red", "gaussian"="blue"))
```

[image: ggplot with legend]

The trick is shifting `color` to *inside* `aes(...)`, and matching them in `scale_color_manual`. I happened to use the same strings as `kernel=`, but that's not strictly necessary. Whatever you choose, though, needs to match the names of `values=` within `scale_color_manual`. (BTW: `labels=` is optional here, unless you want to beautify the strings some; otherwise, it'll use the `color=` from within each `aes()`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what i needed!!